# Check if file can be renamed (moved) without copying

Tags: qt

`QFile::rename` description says:

> If the rename operation fails, Qt will attempt to copy this file's
>   contents to newName, and then remove this file, keeping only newName.

That is undesirable. I need to call `QFile::rename` only if the file can be renamed without copying (e. g. remains on the same disk drive on Windows). Is there a function in Qt that can perform this check (without me having to code it manually for every platform)?

Comment: The copy will happen to the same directory right? So where does the issue with remaining on the same drive come from? And what about its overloaded function, does it have the same property? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#rename

Comment: @Cheiron, I think you misunderstood the question. Moving a file (or folder) within the same drive is very fast because you only need to edit the file table - no data transfer. Moving across drives is equivalent to copying and then deleting the source. I need to check if the given file or folder can be moved to the given location without copy (in the fast manner).

Comment: It's not Qt, but it gives a possible hint about a possible solution : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44249/how-to-check-if-two-directories-or-files-belong-to-same-filesystem

Comment: @valir: thanks. Not Qt is fine, I'm debating writing my own file system library.

Comment: Could you try moving the file under a different name in the same folder, thus skipping the possibility of a copy operation?

Comment: @JonHarper, what do you mean? I need to move the file A to location B. The copy algorithm depends on whether the file can be renamed or has to be copied.

Comment: That's a complete failure on my part. I didn't realize there isn't a `QFile::move()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up getting and checking the drive number on Windows (`PathGetDriveNumber`) and drive ID on Unix (`stat` function and `st_dev` field of the `stat` structure). Seems to work as expected so far.